# Ruby on Rails Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

how can I generate a RoR route like this one:

> Prefix: gateway
>
> verb: post
>
> URI Pattern: /region/:id/gateway
>
> Controller#Action: region#gateway

I tried with

```
resources :region, :only => :show do
    post :gateway, :only => :show
end
```

but is generating by default a route to show the regions

> /region/:id(.:format)

I want to skip the regions show action and only keep it the /region/:id/gateway route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post "gateway/region/:id/gateway" => "region#gateway"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to Rails [routing documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). It's well documented.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use resources, You may write:

```
resources :region do
 member do
    post :gateway
 end
end
```

It will be recognized as:

region/:id/gateway

You can't use "only" because it reduce to one action!